# Definition and Initialization of a tuple whose components are of the same templated class, but with different specialisations

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, recursion, template-meta-programming

I am new to c++ metaprogramming. I tried to look at other answers, but I was not able to find one that could suit my problem.
Or simply I was not able to apply it to my case.
Here I will post a simplified version of the code, to highlight the main features which I would like to obtain.

What I would like to achieve, is the construction of a `std::tuple` of dimension `N` (`N` known at compile-time),
whose components type is given by a template class, `MyType`, depending on two parameters `M` and `N`. 
`M` is fixed, while the type of the tuple component `i` is actually `MyType<M,i>`, for `i=0,...,N`.
Since I have to define recursively a tuple of these types, I have considered the `DefineType` template.

```
// general definition
template<Integer M, Integer N>
struct DefineType
{
    using rest = typename DefineType<M, N-1>::type;
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval< std::tuple< MyType<M,N>>>(),
                                         std::declval<rest>() ));
};

// specialization for N=0
template<Integer M>
struct DefineType<M,0>
{
 using type = typename std::tuple< MyType<M,0> >;
};
```

This should produce the following types:

`DefineType< M, N=0 >`:  `std::tuple< MyType< M,0 >  >` ;

`DefineType< M, N=1 >`:  `std::tuple< MyType< M,0 >, MyType< M,1 >  >` ;

`DefineType< M, N=2 >:  std::tuple< MyType< M,0 >, MyType< M,1 > , MyType< M,2 > >` ;

and so on, up to a general `N`.

Then I would like also to initialize a tuple of this kind, based on something which I call `param` of type `Param`. For doing this,
I write a code of this kind:

```
// general definition
template<Integer M, Integer N>
typename DefineType<M,N>::type  MyClass(Param param)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(std::tuple<MyType<M,N>>(MyType<M,N>(param)), 
                                  MyClass<M,N-1>(param)   )   ;
}
// specialization for N=0
template<Integer M>
typename DefineType<M,0>::type MyClass(Param param)
{
    return std::tuple<MyType<M, 0>>(MyType<M, 0>(param));
}
```

Finally in the main:

```
int main()
{

// M and N given
const auto myobject=MyClass<M,N>(param);

}
```

The code is not compiling, complaining that I am initializing too many times `DefineType<M,N>`. Basically `N` does not reach the base-case, with `N=0`. I do not get why...So for sure the recursive type definition is wrong. But, in addition to this, maybe there are other errors that I do not see. I hope you can help me in understanding how to do this. I apologize, but meta programming is very new (and difficult) to me.

Thank you.

Comment: You want answers strictly C++11 or do you accept also C++14/C++17 solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems in your code.

(1) you say that you want that

`DefineType< M, N=2 >` is `std::tuple< MyType< M,0 >, MyType< M,1 > , MyType< M,2 > >`

but writing

```
using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval< std::tuple< MyType<M,N>>>(),
                                     std::declval<rest>() ));
```

inside `DefineType`, you get the opposite order; you obtain that

`DefineType< M, N=2 >` is `std::tuple<MyType<M, 2>, MyType<M, 1> , MyType<M, 0>>`

If you want the order from zero to `N`, you have to define, in `DefineType`, before the `rest` and then the `N` element; I mean

```
using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(
      std::declval<rest>(),
      std::declval<std::tuple<MyType<M,N>>>() ));
```

(2) The recursion for `MyClass()` function doesn't works because in your recursive version call the same `MyClass()` ever with **two** template parameters

```
template<Integer M, Integer N>
typename DefineType<M,N>::type  MyClass(Param param)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(std::tuple<MyType<M,N>>(MyType<M,N>(param)), 
                                  MyClass<M,N-1>(param)   )   ;
} // you call the second parameter .........^^^
  // also when N is 1 (and N-1 is 0)
```

so the base-case (defined with only one template parameter) never matches.

Unfortunately partial template specialization doesn't works for template functions, so you can use partial template specialization of structs (see aschepler's answer) or, if you prefer, SFINAE to enable/disable the two versions of `MyClass()` according the value of `N`.

I propose the following solution

```
// specialization for N == 0
template <Integer M, Integer N>
typename std::enable_if<(N == 0), typename DefineType<M,0>::type>::type
   MyClass(Param param)
 { return std::tuple<MyType<M, 0>>(MyType<M, 0>(param)); }

// general definition
template <Integer M, Integer N>
typename std::enable_if<(N > 0u), typename DefineType<M,N>::type>::type
   MyClass(Param param)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(
       MyClass<M,N-1>(param),
       std::tuple<MyType<M,N>>(MyType<M,N>(param)) );
}
```

Observe that now the ground case (`N == 0`) has two template parameter but is enabled only when `N` is zero. The other case in enabled only when `N > 0`.

Observe also that you have to write before the ground case version because it is used by the recursive version.

Observe also that I've switched the order of rest/actual type.

If you can use C++14, so `std::make_index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence`, I strongly suggest to avoid recursion and to follow the aschepler's suggestion.

You can also avoid recursion for the `DefineType` itself using specialization as follows

```
template <Integer, Integer N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N+1u>>
struct DefineType;

template <Integer M, Integer N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct DefineType<M, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 { using type = std::tuple<MyType<M, Is>...>; };
```

The following is a full compiling C++14 example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

using Integer = std::size_t;
using Param = int;

template <Integer M, Integer N>
struct MyType
 { MyType (Param) {} };

template <Integer, Integer N, typename = std::make_index_sequence<N+1u>>
struct DefineType;

template <Integer M, Integer N, std::size_t ... Is>
struct DefineType<M, N, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
 { using type = std::tuple<MyType<M, Is>...>; };

template <Integer M, Integer N>
std::enable_if_t<(N == 0), typename DefineType<M,0>::type>
   MyClass(Param param)
 { return std::tuple<MyType<M, 0>>(MyType<M, 0>(param)); }

// general definition
template <Integer M, Integer N>
std::enable_if_t<(N > 0u), typename DefineType<M,N>::type>
   MyClass(Param param)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(
       MyClass<M,N-1>(param),
       std::tuple<MyType<M,N>>(MyType<M,N>(param)) );
}

int main ()
 {
   using t0 = typename DefineType<42u, 0u>::type;
   using u0 = std::tuple<MyType<42u, 0u>>;
   using t1 = typename DefineType<42u, 1u>::type;
   using u1 = std::tuple<MyType<42u, 0u>, MyType<42u, 1u>>;
   using t2 = typename DefineType<42u, 2u>::type;
   using u2 = std::tuple<MyType<42u, 0u>, MyType<42u, 1u>, MyType<42u, 2u>>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<t0, u0>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<t1, u1>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<t2, u2>::value, "!" );

   auto const myobject = MyClass<42u, 2u>(12); 
 }
```

Comment: `std::enable_if_t` is C++14; to be C++11-compatible, we must use `typename enable_if<...>::type`.

Comment: @aschepler - yes... obviously... I've written a C++14 solution but I've forgotten to correct; thanks.

Comment: Point 1). Yes I forgot to change the order, but that seemed to be the less important thing.

Point 2). Thanks, I did not know that, now it works!

Added +1, but is not visible because it is my first post...

Comment: @Garo be sure to mark it as the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: The 'MyClass' can be defined without SFINAE. Observing that 'DefinedType' actually returns a tuple, simply 'return make_tuple(MyType<M, Is>(param)...);'.

Comment: @Red.Wave - Yes. Is the aschepler's solution.

Comment: @max66 . Meta programming gives me a headache. One often misses what's in front of him.

Comment: @max66 programmers are crazy

Answer (score 2):

Given the definitions

```
template<Integer M, Integer N>
typename DefineType<M,N>::type  MyClass(Param param)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(std::tuple<MyType<M,N>>(MyType<M,N>(param)), 
                                  MyClass<M,N-1>(param)   )   ;
}
template<Integer M>
typename DefineType<M,0>::type MyClass(Param param)
{
    return std::tuple<MyType<M, 0>>(MyType<M, 0>(param));
}
```

what you have is two overloaded distinct function templates.  The second is not a "partial specialization" of the first because there is no such thing a function template partial specialization, only class template specializations.  (And so the call `MyClass<M,N-1>(param)` can't possibly match the second template, even if it had been previously declared, since the second one only accepts one template argument, meaning the first template is infinitely recursive.)

One solution could be to use a helper class template:

```
namespace MyClass_detail {
    template<Integer M, Integer N>
    struct helper {
        static typename DefineType<M,N>::type build(const Param& param)
        {
            return std::tuple_cat(
                std::tuple<MyType<M,N>>(MyType<M,N>(param)), 
                MyClass<M,N-1>(param));
        }
    };

    template<Integer M>
    struct helper<M, 0> {
        static typename DefineType<M,0>::type build(const Param& param)
        {
            return std::tuple<MyType<M, 0>>(MyType<M, 0>(param));
        }
    };
}

template<Integer M, Integer N>
typename DefineType<M,N>::type MyClass(Param param)
{
    return MyClass_detail::helper<M,N>::build(Param);
}
```

Though I would recommend taking advantage of [`std::make_integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).  (This is a C++14 feature, and I see your question is tagged C++11. If you can't use C++14 or later, a search should turn up some replacement implementations for `make_integer_sequence` and related tools that can be used in C++11.)

```
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

namespace MyClass_detail {
    template<Integer M, Integer N, Integer ...Inds>
    auto MyClass_helper(const Param &param, std::integer_sequence<Integer, Inds...>)
    {
        return std::make_tuple(MyType<M, N-Inds>(param)...);
    }
}

template<Integer M, Integer N>
auto MyClass(Param param)
{
    return MyClass_detail::MyClass_helper<M,N>(
        param, std::make_integer_sequence<Integer, N+1>{});
}

// And if DefineType is wanted for other uses:
template<Integer M, Integer N>
using DefineType = decltype(MyClass<M,N>(std::declval<Param>()));
```

See the [full working demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b71624c757443b92).